# How to judge an element in a numpy array?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Here is tow array

```
a=np.array([[0, 0, 0],[0, 2, 0],[0, 0, 0]])
b=np.array([0,1,0])
```

I try the code

```
print((b==a).any())
```

It returns True. What I want is to judge if b in a.
How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "judge"? What should the result be, and according to what reasoning? What steps should be taken in order to check?